# Card Counting with Switch instead of If Else if. Why do I not need to also use RETURN?

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner in javascript, so apologies in advanced if this is a dumb question. So, I've noticed that this question has been asked before, but that question was using IF ELSE statements. I'm trying to do it with SWITCH instead.

What i wanted to know is whether i need to also type in RETURN before count++ or count-- inside the SWITCH. I was using a website that provided this question, and my only error was that i used RETURN. The other post used IF ELSE IF and used RETURN.

Can anybody explain why i didn't need to use RETURN?

```
let count = 0;

function cc(card) {
switch (card){
case 2:
case 3:
case 4:
case 5:
case 6:
count++;
break;

case 7: case 8: case 9:
count;
break;

case 10: case "J": case "Q": case "K": case "A":
return count--;
break;
} 
if (count>0){
  return count+" Bet";  
} else {
    return count+" Hold";
} 
}
```

Comment: Return terminates the function and leaves a value. In your case it's either bet or hold otherwise if there's no return all you'll get is `undefined`. Don't use return in a `switch()` it defeats the purpose of having it.

Comment: @zer00ne can you tell me specifically in what kind of situation should i not use return and i can use return in a switch?

Comment: Hey here's an [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72623573/2813224) of what I meant. `switch()` isn't everyone's cup of tea, but I'll use it on occasion as long as the conditions are no more than 5.

Answer (score 0):

## Update

### Do not add `return` to a `switch()`'s `case` block

Interrupting the flow gives you no advantage and more than likely error prone code that will not log any runtime errors.

In **Example C** are three functions:

| Function | Description | Icon |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `A(card)` | The original version of `cc(card)` **without the added `return`s** |  |
| `B(card)` | The modified version of `cc(card)` **with `return`s short circuiting each `case`** | ⛔ |
| `C(card)` | The modified version of `B(card)` **with prefixed operators that fix `B(card)`** | ⚠️ |

### `switch()` is Fragile

A `return` before the `break` is a short circuit. Short circuit in programming context is inserting an early termination of a function/method when a condition is meet. I use this technique frequently but never in a `switch()`. `switch()` is a very readable yet bulky function if you deviate from how it's normally used it will usually cause a hiccup -- something inaccurate or incorrect and too slight to notice since it's not a runtime error.

Take for instance the line marked with a warning sign ⚠️ in **Example A** (also abstracted in **Figure I**)

**Figure I**

```
return count--;
break;
```

So any 10 or face card is short circuited so it never reaches `break` nor will it reach the last condition that determines whether to bet
or hold which is the whole point of this function. Now if we were to pass an **A♤**:

**Figure II**

```
cc('A');
// returns a 0 / expected -1
```

Why did it not decrement `count`? Because it never got the chance to be evaluated due to being short circuited. Originally, all cards went through the switch got it's value then when it reached the last condition, it would be evaluated and it's current values set to 1, 0, or -1. If you have your heart set on using returns before a `break`, change the counters from post to pre (see **Figure III**).

**Figure III**

```
return ++counter;
```

When the in/decrement is prefixed to the value, it is evaluated before it's stored so you'll get accurate results. Like I said, there's no point in using the `switch()` if `return` is used within it.

- **Example A** is the **OP** (**O**riginal **P**ost)
- **Example B** is a refactor of OP
- **Example C** is a side-by-side comparison between OP with short circuit  and OP without short circuit

### Example A

**Original Answer**

```js
let count = 0;

function cc(card) {
  switch (card) {
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
      count++;
      break;

    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
      count;
      break;

    case 10:
    case "J":
    case "Q":
    case "K":
    case "A":
      return count--; // ⚠️
      break;
  }
  if (count > 0) {
    return count + " Bet";
  } else {
    return count + " Hold";
  }
}

console.log(cc('A'));
```

### Example B

**More Blackjack Rules Applied**

```js
/**
 * @desc - Formats output to console
 * @param {any} data - Limited like JSON
 */
const msg = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

/**
 * @desc - Given an unknown amount of numbers and 
 *         strings that represent a set of 52 playing 
 *         cards, it'll calculate: 
 *         score   points[0]
 *         hint    points[1]
 *         aces    points[2]
 * @param {array<rest>} cards - One or more numbers and
                        strings.
 * @return {array<number>} An array of 3 numbers 
 *                         see @desc
 */
const score = (...cards) => {
  let tuple = [...cards].reduce((points, current) => {
    points[0] += current === 'A' ? 11 : typeof current == 'string' ? 10 : current;
    points[1] += current < 7 ? 1 : current > 9 ? -1 : 0;
    return points;
  }, [0, 0]);
  let aces = [...cards].filter(c => c === 'A').length;
  tuple.push(aces);
  return tuple;
}

/**
 * @desc - Given an array of 3 numbers, it calculates,
 *         adjusts, and determines the flow of a 
 *         blackjack game
 * @param {array<number>} score - The output of score()
 * @return {string} A msg to inform the player of 
 *                  current score, a suggestion of what
 *                  to do next, or when the player busts
 */
const hand = score => {
  while (score[0] > 21) {
    if (score[2] > 0) {
      score[2] -= 1;
      score[1] += 1;
      score[0] -= 10;
    } else {
      return msg(`${score[0]}, bust!`);
    }
  }
  if (score[0] === 21) {
    return msg('BLACKJACK!');
  }
  let action = score[1] > 0 ? 'make a wager' : 'stand';
  return msg(`${score[0]}, you should ${action}.`);
}

hand(score('A', 4, 10));
hand(score(2, 9, 3, 9));
hand(score(10, 'K'));
hand(score(6, 2));
hand(score('A', 'K'));
```

### Example C

**Wrong vs. Right**

```js
let count = 0;
let countA = 0;
let countB = 0;
let countC = 0;

function A(card) {
  console.info('Test ' + count + ' ============================');
  console.log('------------A-------------');
  console.log('inA: ' + countA + ' Card: ' + card);
  switch (card) {
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
      countA++; // 
      console.log('A++: ' + countA);
      break;

    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
      countA; // 
      console.log('A: ' + countA);
      break;

    case 10:
    case "J":
    case "Q":
    case "K":
    case "A":
      countA--; // 
      console.log('A--: ' + countA);
      break;
  }
  if (countA > 0) {
    return countA + " Bet";
  } else {
    return countA + " Hold";
  }
}

function B(card) {
  console.log('------------B⛔-------------')
  console.log('inB: ' + countB + ' Card: ' + card);
  switch (card) {
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
      console.log('B++: ' + countB);
      return countB++; // ⛔
      break;

    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
      console.log('B: ' + countB);
      return countB; // ⛔
      break;

    case 10:
    case "J":
    case "Q":
    case "K":
    case "A":
      console.log('B--: ' + countB);
      return countB--; // ⛔
      break;
  }
  if (countB > 0) {
    return countB + " Bet";
  } else {
    return countB + " Hold";
  }
}

function C(card) {
  console.log('------------C⚠️-------------');
  console.log('inC: ' + countC + ' Card: ' + card);
  switch (card) {
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
      console.log('--C: ' + countC + '⚠️');
      return ++countC; // ⚠️
      break;

    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
      console.log('C: ' + countC);
      return countC; // ⚠️
      break;

    case 10:
    case "J":
    case "Q":
    case "K":
    case "A":
      console.log('--C: ' + countC + '⚠️');
      return --countC; // ⚠️
      break;
  }
  if (countC > 0) {
    return countC + " Bet";
  } else {
    return countC + " Hold";
  }
}

document.forms.bj.oninput = hit;
document.forms.bj.onreset = reset;

function hit(e) {
  const IO = this.elements;
  let draw = IO.draw.value;
  let card = isNaN(draw) ? draw : +draw;
  let a = A(card);
  let b = B(card);
  let c = C(card);
  IO.A.value = a;
  IO.B.value = b;
  IO.C.value = c;
  count++;
}

function reset(e) {
  count = 0;
  countA = 0;
  countB = 0;
  countC = 0;
}
```

```css
html {
  font: 300 1.5ch/1.2 'Segoe UI';
}

#table {
  display: flex;
  max-width: max-content;
}

legend {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

select,
input {
  display: inline-flex;
  font: inherit;
}

label,
select,
input,
output {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

output {
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
}

#B {
  color: red;
}

.as-console-row::after {
  width: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.as-console-row-code {
  width: 100%;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100% !important;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<form id='bj'>
  <fieldset id='table'>
    <legend>Blackjack</legend>
    <label class='IN'>
    <select id='draw'>
      <option selected>Draw</option>
      <option value='2'>2</option>
      <option value='3'>3</option>
      <option value='4'>4</option>
      <option value='5'>5</option>
      <option value='6'>6</option>
      <option value='7'>7</option>
      <option value='8'>8</option>
      <option value='9'>9</option>
      <option value='10'>10</option>
      <option value='J'>Jack</option>
      <option value='Q'>Queen</option>
      <option value='K'>King</option>
      <option value='A'>Ace</option>
    </select>
    <input type='reset'>
    </label>
    <fieldset>
      <label>
    Original:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
      <output id='A'>&nbsp;</output>
    </label>
      <label>
    Short Circuits:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;⛔<br>
      <output id='B'>&nbsp;</output>
    </label>
      <label>
    Short Circuits<br>Prefixed Operators: ⚠️<br>
      <output id='C'>&nbsp;</output>
    </label>
    </fieldset>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: I think i'm starting to get the picture on when to use and not to use it. let me clarify figure 1 a bit

Let's ignore the if statements after the switch(). Whether or not i used the return, the code will still decrement the count value by 1, right? the same will happen for the ++ if i also use return.

but because i still have the if else statement to go through, it won't achieve my goal 100% because i terminated it early by using return inside the switch(). If i don't need the if else statements, the code still works. 

am i correct? thank you for being patient and being super thorough!

Comment: The counter is incremented to it's true value (1) when it gets evaluated by that if statement `if (count > 0) {...` and it's returned as (1). Being short circuited it returns as 0 -- once `return` happens the function terminates and everything within the function gets garbage collected. The counter is outside the function but it's still 0 because nothing is was planned for this value until count is called upon during another run of the function. Now if the increment was on the left side of the value, it would be updated properly before the return fires.

Comment: alright i understand. however, since i wanted the code to continue to the if else statement, i shouldn't use return at all, right? so unless i have any other additional code to go through, i can use return.

Comment: @JuanYeremia see update and **Example C**